# Unexpected white gap (4mm wide) between edge of PDF page and start of a background

Tags: context

When processing my document with ConTeXt, I do not understand why there appears a gap between the leftmost edge of my PDF document and the left edge of my background layer.

I have made an MWE which exhibits this behavior:

```
\definelayer[mybkgr][x=0mm,y=0mm,
  width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background={mybkgr}]

\setlayer[mybkgr][x=0mm,y=10cm]{
  \blackrule[height=0.3\paperheight,
   width=\paperwidth,color=orange]}

\starttext
    \strut
\stoptext
```

I also tried with hoffset instead of x, with the same result.

This gap can be canceled by setting a hoffset to -4mm. But why does it appear in the first place ? am I missing something ?

(note : In order to be sure that it's not a PDF-viewer-specific behavior, I checked the resulting PDF using evince, xpdf and okular)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a spurious space in your code:

```
\definelayer[mybkgr][x=0mm,y=0mm,
  width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background={mybkgr}]

\setlayer[mybkgr][x=0mm,y=10cm]{% <--
  \blackrule[height=0.3\paperheight,
   width=\paperwidth,color=orange]}

\starttext
    \strut
\stoptext
```

[image]